# How to restrict user to use 1 email id or phone number in only 1 device

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm developing an Android app with Android studio and firebase authentication and I want to restrict user to use 1 email id or 1 phone number in only 1 device .any suggestion how can I archive this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication was not designed to support this case. It's intended for users to be able to use a Firebase app on multiple devices.  It's also expected that a user could create multiple accounts.  There is no way of limiting the number of accounts a person can create.